# jquery fade out and on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hope you are all doing well.

So I have gallery that is not using any plugin

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var index =1;
    var images = ['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg'];
    var caption_text = ["title1","title2","title3"];
    function rotateImage()
    {

       $('#gallery').fadeOut('fast', function() 
      { 
        $(this).attr('src','<?php echo base_url()."assets/highlight/";?>'+ images[index]);
        $('span').text(caption_text[index]);
        $(this).fadeIn('fast', function() 
        { 
          if (index == images.length-1)
          {
            index = 0;
          }
          else
          {
            index++;
          }

        });
      });

    } 
    setInterval (rotateImage, 2500);

$('.thumb').on('click', function() {
        var img = $('<img />', {src    : this.src,
                                'class': 'highlight_img'
                  });
        var imageTitle = $(this).attr("title");      
        $('.highlight').html(img).show();
        $('.highlight').append("<br/><span class='highlight_caption'>"+imageTitle+"</span>");
        setInterval (rotateImage, 5000);  
    });
 });
```

and this is my html

```
<div class='col-md-12 highlight'>
    <img id='gallery' src='<?php  echo site_url('assets/highlight/1.jpg');?>' height='300' class='highlight_img'/><br/>
    <span id='highlight_caption' class='highlight_caption'>title1</span>
</div>

<div class='list'>
 <div><img class='thumb' src='<?php  echo site_url('assets/highlight/1.jpg');?>' height='75' title='title1'/></div>
 <div><img class='thumb' src='<?php  echo site_url('assets/highlight/2.jpg');?>' height='75' title='title2'/></div>
 <div><img class='thumb' src='<?php  echo site_url('assets/highlight/3.jpg');?>' height='75' title='title3'/></div>
```

Now, I can do the image rotation when the page load with no problem. Also, when i click the image thumbnail, the #gallery div will also change image based on the thumbnail I click

But, when I invoke the thumbnail on click function, the rotateImage() does not work anymore, I need to refresh the page to get the image rotating again.

How should I code to perform this?

Thank you!

EDIT:

Sorry for not being clear
My question is, I have put "setInterval (rotateImage, 5000);" inside .thumb on click() function, I know it's running because I tried to console.log, and the script does execute, BUT why the image isn't changing?

Comment: with this question you wont get much answeres. no one will code for you. they will help you to find bugs so change your question to something like `how can i avoid this issue` or some like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this;

**JQUERY**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var index         = 1,
        images        = ['300x300','290x300','280x300'],
        caption_text  = ['title1','title2','title3'],
        timer         = null;

    function rotateImage () {

       $('#gallery').fadeOut('fast', function() { 
       $(this).attr('src','http://www.placehold.it/'+ images[index]);
       $('span').text(caption_text[index]);
       $(this).fadeIn('fast', function() { 
           if (index == images.length-1) {
             index = 0;
           } else {
             index++;
           }
        });
      });
    } 
timer = setInterval (rotateImage, 2500);

$('.thumb').on('click', function() {
    var $this      = $(this),
        img        = $this.attr('src'),
        imageTitle = $this.attr('title');      
    $('.highlight')
        .children('img')
        .attr('src',img)
        .show()
        .end()
            .children('.highlight_caption')
                .text(imageTitle);
        clearInterval(timer);
        setInterval (rotateImage, 5000);  
    });
 });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='col-md-12 highlight'>
    <img id='gallery' src='http://www.placehold.it/300x300' height='300' class='highlight_img'/>    <br/>
    <span id='highlight_caption' class='highlight_caption'>title1</span>
</div>

<div class='list'>
    <div><img class='thumb' src='http://www.placehold.it/400x400' height='75' title='title1'/>    </div>
 <div><img class='thumb' src='http://www.placehold.it/500x500' height='75' title='title2'/></div>
 <div><img class='thumb' src='http://www.placehold.it/350x350' height='75' title='title3'/></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DKw8D/6/